# Ros running on 2 machines, one master, subscriber not getting any message

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have the following configuration with two machines running on Ubuntu:
On one machine I run the ros master, and a listener (tutorial one)

On the other I have a talker (again from the tutorial).
I set the ROS_MASTER_URI as specified in http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines.
I am able to ping between the machines, and use netcat to send msgs back and forth from the command lines.
I have allowed port 11311 with ufw.

If I run the talker, the listener doesn't get any message.
If I run rqt_graph it shows the nodes and the topic on which they publish/subscribe. The listener node's color is in red, and nothing changes if I hover on it.

Any idea for what could be the issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255119/ros-running-on-2-machines,-one-master,-subscriber-not-getting-any-message/) by [highWaters](https://answers.ros.org/users/25790/highwaters/) on ROS Answers with karma: 176 on 2017-02-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-02-20**:
It's likely that you don't have your ROS environment variables setup correctly. Please edit your question to describe the exact values for ROS_MASTER_URI, ROS_HOSTNAME, and ROS_IP on both machines.

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.ros.org/users/3396/dcconner/) on 2017-02-20**:
If you are using HOSTNAME, you need to have consistent /etc/hosts files on both machines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Disabling ufw completely solved the problem. The weird thing is that, this was working once without the need to disable ufw.

---

Originally posted by [highWaters](https://answers.ros.org/users/25790/highwaters/) with karma: 176 on 2017-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arminf82](https://answers.ros.org/users/45412/arminf82/) on 2019-09-07**:
You can simply allow traffic in your LAN, no need to deactivate ufw completely.

$ sudo ufw allow from 192.168.178.0/24